# How to create a trigger that uses INSERT , DELETE , UPDATE events

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger for logging.So i need event names of INSERT,UPDATE or DELETE.i.e : one of these statements is used in query execution my trigger will trig and starts logging.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER LogBuses 
 ON  Bus_table 
 AFTER INSERT,DELETE
 AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @PlateNo nvarchar(50)
IF INSERT//something like that-INSERTING- DELETING
    SELECT @PlateNo=PlateNo from inserted
insert into Logger (EffectedTable,ActionName,EffectDate,EffectedID) 
VALUES ('Bus_table','Insert',SYSDATETIME (),@PlateNo);
ELSE IF DELETE 
    SELECT @PlateNo=PlateNo from deleted
insert into Logger (EffectedTable,ActionName,EffectDate,EffectedID) VALUES ('Bus_table','Insert',SYSDATETIME (),@PlateNo);
```

END
GO

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use the `inserted` and `deleted` tables. It's inserted if just the `inserted` table is populated, deleted if just the `deleted` table is populated, and updated if both tables are populated. Use `if exists (select 1 from inserted)` to test.

```
if exists (select 1 from inserted) and exists (select 1 from deleted)
--update
else if exists (select 1 from inserted)
--insert
else if exists (select 1 from deleted)
--delete
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure that logs, and triggers for each event, that call the procedure, passing the needed data.